# Excel-like filtering in LightSwitch

Tags: excel, filter, telerik, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm pretty new to LightSwitch and trying to make a responsive filter feature to my tables.

[This is what it looks like in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpxPE.png)

Telerik extensions has this [feature](http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight/gridview.aspx) and you can use that in LightSwitch, but I can't afford the license.

Is there any other way to accomplish the same thing without paying $999? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [filter control extension available here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlight/Filter-Control-for-eb947bdc), but it seems that both the VS10 and VS12 versions are not fully functional (I did not have time to check by myself).